# Jade when passing object/array from router get error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm exploring Jade as a view engine in Node and spent 3 hours not being able to pass an object (the response from the database) to Jade view without getting error.

From my router `all` is an array with objects:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/all', function(req, res){
    db.findAll().then(function(all){
        res.render("index", { creators: all });
    });
});
```

Jade view:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title my jade template
    body
        .comment_list
            each el in creators
                p= el.creator
```

As you see it's pretty simple. I've seen more than 20 examples of using Jade and do the same and always get this error:

```
> TypeError: index.jade:7
  5|     body
  6|         .comment_list
> 7|             each el in creators
  8|                 p= el.creator
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Until I finally tried to do a check `if(typeof(creators) != "undefined")` before `each el in creators` and guess what... magic happened. The error disappeared.

I'm writing this post for reference to all people struggling with the same issuse and also I'd like to ask what is the reason for this error and why nowhere in the documentation of Jade is mentioned one should make such a check for undefined before iterating through a collection?

Answer (score 2):

It is a common pattern in Jade to check for a variable's existence before trying operate on it.

From the Jade documentation on [iterations](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html):

> The object or array to iterate over is just plain JavaScript so it can be a variable or the result of a function call or almost anything else.

```
- var values = [];
ul
  each val in values.length ? values : ['There are no values']
    li= val
```

---

Under the hood, Jade is using standard JavaScript to when you call `each`.

So trying to call `each` on something that doesn't exist is like trying to do:

```
for(var i=0; i < undefined.length; i++) { ... }
```

Which errors because `length` isn't a real property of `undefined`.

Totally understand your frustration, as its dealing with undefined data is something pains a lot of people in JavaScript.

Comment: Hey @Steven Schobert, thank you for your explanation! However why undefined? I'm passing an existing object, but if there is no if/check - it throws the error. I really can't see what the logic is behind that behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure it's an array being passed every time? Try putting `console.log(all)` right before your `render` call.

Comment: Yeah, if I console.log(all) right before your render call. –  Steven Schobert 9 hours ago it's undefined, but if I declare: h2= creators it renders/prints the whole object without problem. But if I want to get particular object from the creators object - it throws the error.

P.S How do you highlight pieces of code in the comments?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow your question. What is the value of `all` when you log it? (use backticks \` for inline code)